# Change the text displayed when sharing URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm making a website using WordPress, and I installed Yoast SEO plugin, then I changed the description to the one I need.

But when I share the link, it displays a Latino text.

How can I change this text?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Wordpress administration, not programming

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you are asking. What Latino text can you see? What have you done to try changing it? Is it not just a case of using the settings/admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yoast SEO plugin allows you to add the meta data for the page, and also in a separate tab for Facebook & Twitter cards. Firstly, check you have also updated the fields in the social tabs. If you have done that, allow a few hours, as sometimes I have known it to take a while to render.

Comment: Okay now it works, thanks for the answer.